# Mid-70s Scifi/action film with Mad Max-like characters shooting at flying robot/drones

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a trailer for a film around 1974/75.

People were trying to shoot down flying robot/drones. The clip was a battle scene set in a desert-like setting. Actors/actresses were *Mad Max/Road Warrior* looking; rugged, dirty. The robot/drones made an eerie high pitched scream. They looked a bit like Daleks from Dr. Who. Similar to Daleks in shape- dome top, guns in front at center of body.

Language was in English.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: That's a bit terse. I guess just having seen the trailer you can't say much, but let's give it a try: was it in English, was it a translation? Do you remember if any character had a "specific" trait? (Funny hair, necklace, scar, whatever)

Comment: It was in English. The clip was a battle scene, set in a desert like setting. The people were MadMax/Road warrior dressed; rugged looking and dirty. The robot/drones made an erie high pitched scream. They looked a little like daleks from Dr. Who.

Comment: You might want to [edit] that into the question, as well as any other info you might be remembering. Every detail helps :)

Comment: In what sense did they look like Daleks?

Answer (score 1):

High-pitched screaming robots in a sort of after-the-end setup makes me think of *[Screamers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_(1995_film))*.

> In the year 2078, the planet Sirius 6B, once a thriving mining hub, has been reduced to a toxic wasteland by a war between the mining company, known as the New Economic Bloc (NEB), and the Alliance, a group of former mining and science personnel. Five years into the war, Alliance scientists created and deployed Autonomous Mobile Swords (AMS) — artificially intelligent self-replicating machines that hunt down and kill NEB soldiers on their own. They are nicknamed "screamers" because of a high-pitched noise they emit as they attack. Screamers track targets by their heartbeats, so Alliance soldiers wear "tabs" which broadcast a signal canceling out the wearer's heartbeat and rendering them "invisible" to the machines.

It's from 1995, though. Could you be confused on the date?

**Trailer**

Comment: The baddies don't look much like Daleks and the timescale is very far off

Comment: @valorum True, but we've had other times the time frame has been that far off, and it could lead to them clarifying why it doesn't fit.

Comment: I thought of Screamers too. I didn't think it was a good fit because I don't recall there being flying Dalek-like drones, and the characters were dressed as either civilians or soldiers, not "Mad Max" style.